# What type of data should I provide to grafana geomap?

Tags: grafana, geomap

This is grafana geomap. It gets data from prometheus. I configured the worldmap's type, but it didn't work. What data type should I provide to grafana geomap?
[image]

Comment: Looks like you are trying to show points based on coordinates. What do you see if you enable the "Table view" toggle at the top?

Answer (score 0):

According to PS, you metric has longitude and latitude labels. In this case, you need to add Labels to fields Transform to your query and set Location Mode to "Auto":
[image]